# compileRetrolambdaRelease java finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: java, lambda

Error:Execution failed for task compileRetrolambdaRelease.

> Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_102.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

following code makes compile error(above)

```
public class Main {
    public static class Parent {
        public Parent(IParent ia) {}

        public interface IParent {
            void onException(Throwable e);
        }
    }

    public class Child extends Parent {
        public Child() {
            super(e -> new ExceptionHandler());
        }
    }

    protected class ExceptionHandler {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because **class ExceptionHandler isn't static.** In this case Compiler should throw exception below, but it doesn't. Is it a compiler bug?

> cannot reference `super(e -> new ExceptionHandler());` this before supertype constructor has been called following code makes compile error that isn't described by compiler correctly but throws error above